# Parse String DateTime containing TimeZone Info

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert a string value to a datetime value but am getting a System.FormatException error. This is because of the timezone info which is part of the date string. Is there any method which will be able to handle this conversion?

```
string date = "Wed, 04 Jan 2012 20:18:00 EST";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

Comment: CST = Central Standard Time in the US and Australia as well as China Standard Time.  If you don't have a problem now then you will later.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there's any [custom date and time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) which will parse or format a time zone abbreviation. You'll have to strip it out, parse the local part, work out which time zone is meant from the abbreviation (good luck with that - they're ambiguous) and then apply that time zone to the local time to get a UTC value (again, this can be ambiguous).

If you're in control of the format at all, I would try to avoid including time zone information if you can, or include an *offset* rather than a time zone if that's all that's important (an offset doesn't give the same information of course), or an unambiguous time zone identifier if you really need the time zone. Note that .NET uses the Windows system time zone identifiers; my own [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project uses the more widespread [Olson / zoneinfo / tz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) identifiers, if that's helpful to you.

Comment: I am not sure could it be possible via `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: How would you propose doing it? `DateTimeOffset` doesn't use a different set of custom date and time format string specifiers, so unless I've missed something on that page, I don't think there's anything built-in...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping I would not have to go that route. Unfortunately I dont have control over the format. I have seen the SyndicationFeed reader is able to parse similar dates so was hoping the is a simpler method.

Comment: @JonSkeet Am not sure coz i tried something like `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-02-01 11:35:47.743-04:00")` so thought maybe possible

Comment: Could be if EST is replaced with the Offset value but maybe its not a good idea at all

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Yes, if you get an offset in the input string there are ways of parsing that - but not the time zone abbreviation.