# C# string to DateTime with timezone

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I want to format the string : "2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200" to a dateTime with this format.
so I think it must be "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"?

when I tried this

```
   // starttime =  {20/04/2012 10:10:00} without my +0200!
DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
// And this gave me a format exception : {System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
        DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

SOLUTION GIVEN BY "V4Vendetta" :

You should try using DateTimeOffset instead of the DateTime

```
DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here you get the Offset (2 hrs) too which could be computed with your DateTime (10:10) value and get your desired out put (result.DateTime + result.Offset)

Comment: Have a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754563/parse-string-datetime-containing-timezone-info)

Comment: As per my knowledge your input should be "2012-04-20 10:10:00+02:00"

Comment: @user1264255 Yes, it will help you on your feature questions ;).

Comment: Useful MSDN link for roundtripping dates/times in .NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882584(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should try using `DateTimeOffset` instead of the `DateTime`

```
DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here you get the `Offset` (2 hrs) too which could be computed with your `DateTime` (10:10) value and get your desired out put (result.DateTime + result.Offset)

Comment: Glad ! you should attempt to mark as answers for all your questions *which helped you* and encourage others.

Comment: Such a useful thing to have!

Answer (score 2):

use "2012-04-20 10:10:00 +02:00" instead of " "2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200"

Comment: then i got the same when i just convert to datetime. 
result :  // starttime =  {20/04/2012 10:10:00} without my +0200

Comment: It should be in +02:00 time zone already. Please check by toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz")

Comment: That's right, but i realy needed it in DateTime. V4Vendetta has given me the right solution. But still Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) seems to have exactly what you're looking for. Per said article, you should be using `{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2009 12:00:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: This does not do anything for timezone.