# C# Parse DateTime from string (custom format)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this DateTime as string: `2015-08-21T10:51:25.9495986+02:00`

How can I parse this string date into a DateTime object?

I usually do this:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;   

DateTime _date;

DateTime.TryParseExact("2015-05-12T12:00:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out _date))
```

But now the end of the DateTime contains `+02:00`. Never faced this format and I believe this has to do something with the Time Region right?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `o` specifier for the format

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2015-08-21T10:51:25.9495986+02:00", "o", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out _date);
```

This will provide you a local time, to convert to universal time you can use `.ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: IMHO parsing to `DateTime` is not appropriate here. Because it _might_ generate different results in different timezone machines. For example; I'm UTC+3 right now and your code generates `21.08.2015 11:51:25` on my machine but in Ideone, [it generates](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3uy7Lb) `21.08.2015 08:51:25`. That's why parsing `DateTimeOffset` can be a better approach in this case.

Comment: @SonerGönül I think you're probably right, albeit the OP *was* asking how to parse to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is here: [C# string to DateTime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293362/c-sharp-string-to-datetime-with-timezone)

But to help:
"You should try using `DateTimeOffset` instead of the `DateTime`"

See the following example:

```
DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-04-20 10:10:00+0200",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: If you found a dup you should just comment about it and when you have more rep you can just vote to close as a dup.  No need to put it in an answer.

Comment: Thanks @juharr, I'll see if I have this sufficient rep to do this.

Comment: You need 3,000 to vote to close.