# Parsing amazon app store purchaseDate receipt string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, in-app-purchase, datetimeoffset, amazon-appstore

The purchase receipt from the amazon app store has a purchase date formatted as "Wed Feb 02 17:28:08 GMT+00:00 2022" however I'm not sure how to properly convert this to a valid DateTime due to the timezone offset being included.

```cs
DateTime.Parse("Wed Feb 02 17:28:08 GMT+00:00 2022");
```

The standard DateTime.Parse function just throws *FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

How can I parse this string as DateTime?

**EDIT:**
A commented suggested DateTimeOffset.Parse however this also gives the same FormatException

```cs
DateTimeOffset.Parse("Wed Feb 02 17:28:08 GMT+00:00 2022", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# string to DateTime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293362/c-sharp-string-to-datetime-with-timezone)

Comment: DateTimeOffset.Parse("Wed Feb 02 17:28:08 GMT+00:00 2022", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); still throws the same FormatException sadly

Comment: Use following :            string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss GMTzzz yyyy";
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed Feb 02 17:28:08 GMT+00:00 2022", format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @jdweng Thanks! This works, you should reply as an answer so I can mark it. However do you know if the amazon receipt will always use GMT?

Comment: It is GMT plus the delta Timezone.  The GMT is just a 3 letter string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` where you pass the expected format string.  The correct format string for your date is `"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz yyyy"`:

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, 
                       "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz yyyy", 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, you'll still have issues if `GMT` doesn't appear in the string, but some other Timezome string does. You could try `TryParseExact` instead, and if it fails to parse then replace the Timezone characters in the string (assuming there will always be 3 characters GMT, CST, etc):

```
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateString,  
                                "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz yyyy", 
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                out var dt))
{    
    // it worked
}
else 
{
    // try to replace the Timezone string
    var replaced = dateString.Replace(dateString.Substring(20, 3), "");
    date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(replaced, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
}
```

To use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` you need to know the expected format string before parsing.