# Convert s string to specific DateTime format with timezone - C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying this code (c#):

```
 string input1 = "2009-11-22 01:01:05 +1:30"
                        string input2 = "2009-11-22 01:01:05"
                        DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
                        DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
                        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss [z]"
                        DateTime orgDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(input1, format, null);
                        DateTime orgDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(input2, format, null);
```

The purposes are:

1. recognize the term "[z]" as optional parameter so both input1 and input2 will be parsed correctly.
2. To get valid DateTime parsed values in orgDate1 and orgDate2.
   The problem:
   I don't manage to get parsed values, even if ignore the optional requirement:

```
  string input1 = "2009-11-22 01:01:05 +1:30"
                        DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
                        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"
                        DateTime orgDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(input1, format, null);
```

I tried many options, like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2009-11-22 00:00:00 1", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z",null)
DateTime.ParseExact("2009-11-22 00:00:00 1", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z",null)
```

But always get formatException.

Only this code works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2009-11-22 00:00:00Z", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ",null)
```

But it returns the exact UTC time zone while I need to get it as parameter.

all is described above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# string to DateTime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293362/c-sharp-string-to-datetime-with-timezone)

Comment: I think that no, it doesn't use the defined "format"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several trials I find that following code works:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2009-11-22 00:00:00+1", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z",null)
```

So remain the other Q - how can I define the format with optional timezone, such that both "2009-11-22 00:00:00+1" and "2009-11-22 00:00:00" will be parsed properly?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).